# a ctl file preventing machine from starting up

Tags: linux, boot, startup

This is a rather ridiculous predicament I find myself in. At some point in the past I've installed a piece of software (ejabberd, if you're curious, but I don't think it really matters which), that is trying to start up right as I boot up my machine. Much later, playing with Erlang/OTP (which ejabberd depends on for starting up), I found a better (for development) way of installing Erlang on the machine, and so I've uninstalled the previously installed one (via apt-get install). Later on, playing with something, I've noticed that erl - the binary for starting up Erlang's virtual machine, among other things - still sits in my /usr/bin. "Ah," - I thought - "I don't need the silly thing, apt-get remove didn't do a good job cleaning up, sudo rm -rf!"...

...welp!

Now when I try to boot, I see a looong line of:

**/usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 60: exec: /usr/bin/erl: not found**

Can't boot - can't uninstall. I can interrupt the startup process and see the option to change boot options and BIOS setup - but don't know if, and how, those might help me to fix the situation. There's  Any ideas? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from some other medium, e.g. from an USB stick. Assuming you are using Debian or Ubuntu, that may work with the installation image for that distribution (you can get into a shell), or you can use something like [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) (which, besides the name, can be booted from various media, including network boot via PXE).

Once you booted and are in a shell, mount the system partition of your harddisk. Inspect damage done with your `rm -rf` (you didn't say in which directory you did that).

If it's something simple you can fix, fix it. Otherwise, you may have to reinstall a (small or large) part of your system. If you need to do a full install, you can save the list of packages (look at `/var/lib/dpkg/status`) you have installed somewhere else before doing that, so you can restore the system to the state it was in. Booting from the installation image of your distribution may be handy for that.

Comment: Or just delete the line in the init scripts that runs `ejabberd`.

Comment: @SatōKatsura: That'll only work if the *only* problem is that `ejabberd` can't start, which was not clear to me from the description - I don't know what was deleted with the `rm -rf`.

Comment: yes, I did create a live USB stick; booting from it I am able to see my hard drive. I think people saying something else must be amiss are right. I've deleted the ejabberdctl file from my /usr/sbin, when booted from the USB stick, but the system still doesn't start. First, it greets me with a "you're running in low-graphics mode", which is something it was doing yesterday too (and I don't know what caused it), but then it just locks up, no matter which way I choose to continue (console or low-graphics)

Comment: "System doesn't start" is not enough information to debug the problem. Please edit the question and tell us (1) which directories you did delete with `rm rf` and (2) what exactly happens when it tries to boot (put the syslog or `dmesg` into a pastebin, if necessary. I still suspect that you've accidentally deleted important parts of the system, but you are the only one who can find out which parts.

Comment: while this didn't solve my real problem, it did provide me with a way to work around the issue which I thought was the problem )

Answer (score 0):

A single non critical service that fails to start, like your XMPP daemon, should not prevent the whole server from starting up. There is probably something else, more critical, that you fail to see.

But one problem at a time. For the time being, you ought to properly reinstall `erlang-base` (the package containing `/usr/bin/erl`) :

```
apt-get install --reinstall erlang-base
```